# Remove all indents and spaces from JSON string except inside its value in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

My problematic string is like this:

```
'{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB\n\n\nBBB"\n}'
```

I want to parse it as JSON object(Hash) by JSON.parse(jsonstring)
The expecting result is:

```
{ "test": "AAAA", "test2": "BBB\nB"}
```

However, I get the error:

```
JSON::ParserError: 809
```

I happend to know that indentaion code in jsonstring be escaped,
so I tried this:

```
escaped_jsonstring = '{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB\n\n\nBBB"\n}'.gsub(/\R/, '\\n')
JSON.parse(escaped_jsonstring)
```

I still have JSON::ParserError.
Indentations outside the key or value may cause this error.
How can I remove `\n`(or \r any indentation code) only outside the key or value in Ruby?

which means,

```
'{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB\n\n\nBBB"\n}'
```

↓

```
'{"test":"AAAA","test2":"BBB\n\n\nBBB"}'
```

Comment: What is the *rule* to be applied that causes `'"BBB\n\n\nBBB"'` to be converted to `"BBB\nB"`.

Comment: Thank you for your support. `"BBB\n\n\nBBB"` should be still "BBB\n\n\nBBB" after removing indentation.

Comment: Where does that "problematic" string come from?

Comment: Thanks. User input json string with indentation in textarea. so "problematic" string comes from user's input. By removing all indentation from string, I can check if it's a valid json structure. but I don't want any indentations or spaces inside the json key-value.

Comment: _"check if it's a valid json structure"_ – well, it's not. JSON requires newlines within strings to be escaped as `\n`. So having unescaped newlines within a JSON string is invalid. And that's why you get the error. Instead of trying to "fix" the malformed JSON, it would probably be better to ask the users to paste valid JSON.

Comment: I meant that I can check valid json by `'{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB\n\n\nBBB"\n}'`→`'{"test":"AAAA","test2":"BBBBBB"}' `.

Comment: > it would probably be better to ask the users to paste valid JSON. Yes, you may be right. but I cannot make any changes in frontend in my case. so I have to deal with this problem at backend after user input...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```rb
'{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB\n\n\nBBB"\n}'.gsub(/\B(\\n)+/, "")
```

`\n"` is considered inside boundary (so i use `\B`), meanwhile `"\n` is considered outside boundary (`\b`), `(\\n)+` to fix case `'...,\n\n\n"test2":...`

**update**
turn out `\s\n` also be considered an inside boundary ... iam not sure there's other cases ...

for now, the updated version

```
'{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB \n\n\n BBB"\n}'
 .gsub(/([{,\"]\s*)\B(\\n)+/) { $1 }
```

**better way**

i found another way to solve your problem, also using `regexp`, now i will scan through the input text (valid or invalid json) then filter follow the pair pattern `"<key>":"<value>"` and don't care anything else outside those pairs, finally output the hash

```rb
 def format(json)
  matches = json.scan(/\"(?<key>[^\"]+)\":\"(?<val>[^\"]+)\",*/)
  matches&.to_h
 end

 format('{\n "test\n parser":"AA\nAA", \n\n"test2":"BBB ? ;\n\n\n  BBB" \n}')
 # {"test\n parser"=>"AA\nAA", "test2"=>"BBB ? ;\n\n\n  BBB"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. but `gsub(/\B(\\n)+/, "")` does not work perfectly. when target string is '{\n"test":"AAAA",\n"test2":"BBB   \n\n\n   BBB"\n}', the result is '{"test":"AAAA","test2":"BBB   BBB"}'. The regex removed necessary indentation in value.

Comment: @user16012143 in that case, you want to only keep `\n` or both `\s` and `\n` ?

Comment: I want to keep both `\s` and `\n` (which means that I don't want to make any changes to key or value in my json. ) Thanks.

Comment: @user16012143 try new one, but iam not sure there's still other cases or not

Comment: @user16012143 my bad, the new one will fail in case `, \n"test2`

Comment: oh...it seems that regexp cannot work perfectly...? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user16012143 try my newest regex.

Comment: oh wow, Although I'm not sure why it works, it seems to work well so far! I'll try to use it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user16012143 the new regex will find all `\n` those have prefix `{`, `,`, `"` and spaces then replace them. as you can see, iam fixed prefixes and it maybe temporary has worked so far but it's high potential to be broken in future, e.g user input `,;\n"test2"`... and it's not good to maintain since you have to keep adding new `stranger` symbols into that regex.

Comment: Thanks! now I understood how it works. and Is there any methods in ruby to do this without regex?

Comment: @user16012143 try my newest solution, i think it works now :D